# BackgroundWorker having everything passed as delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I want to pass the whole code to the BackgroundWorker DoWork event. I see it like that

```
     var c = (MethodInvoker)delegate
     {
           object all = z.bg_getAllPlugins("size=10");
           propertyGrid1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
           {
                propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = all;
           });
     };
     call.RunWorkerAsync(c);
```

But when I try to invoke it

```
    private void call_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(e.Argument);
    }
```

, it invokes it on the Main thread, thus making the BackgroundWorker not doing it's job. Is it possible for the BackgroundWorker to have a Delegate invoked in DoWork thread?

Now just to pass the argument, being a delegate MethodInvoker.

Comment: You're calling `Invoke` - why? That's what's putting it back on the main thread...

Comment: The question is how not to let that happen, I have no idea what the syntax would be for the BackgroundWorker to do what's in the Delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `Invoke` from the `call_DoWork` method - and `Control.Invoke` *invokes a delegate on the UI thread*. You just want to invoke the delegate on the *current* thread:

```
var work = (MethodInvoker) e.Argument;
work();
```

(That's assuming your delegate is always a `MethodInvoker` of course.)